# Which yum repositories for Oracle Linux 7 can I use to install Kubernetes?

Tags: yum, kubernetes

I've been able to successfully install Kubernetes in a CentOS 7 testing environment using the "virt7-testing" repo as described in the CentOS "[Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config.md)" in the Kubernetes github repo.  My production environment will be running on Oracle Linux 7, and so far enabling "virt7-testing" on OL7 hasn't been working.

Are there any other yum repositories out there that are compatible with OL7 and include Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best solution to pull outside of OEL, but I couldn't find an OEL repository with these packages, so I used this:

```
[]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/virt7-common.repo
[virt7-common]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Comment: This worked fine in setting up my kubernetes cluster on OEL 7.2 (masters and minions).

Comment: Just a small addition, you need to install the centos 7 GPG key:

rpm --import http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

Comment: I get this error when I use the above on my OEL7.2. Error: Package: 2:container-selinux-2.10-2.el7.noarch (virt7-common)
           Requires: policycoreutils >= 2.5-11
           Installed: policycoreutils-2.2.5-20.0.1.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.2)
               policycoreutils = 2.2.5-20.0.1.el7
Any clue?

Comment: updated all packages by adding this repo as well https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/ol7-downloading-yum-repo.html and it worked. thx

Answer (score -1):

A good start would be the rapidly updated fedora / epel kubernetes repositories.

Something like (untested)

`yum --enablerepo=updates-testing install kubernetes kubernetes-devel flanneld docker`

Should do it for you.